# how to create json feed

Tags: c#, json

any one explain me how to  develop following type of json.
 Json feed contains parent and child nodes with database comtent.

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },


  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) and paste your json. It will create the following classes for you

```
public class Phone
{
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string home { get; set; }
    public string office { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public Phone phone { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Create the *RootObject*, fill the properties and then serialize it.

That is all.

```
var root = new RootObject();
//fill the properties
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

Comment: how to fill the properties from database value using javasriptserializer

Comment: JsonConvert showing error